# Angular Config Doesn't Work

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, factory

I have the following code. The `console.log(apiServerConstants.url)` line in the factory returns `undefined` when I inject an AuthService in other code. Why?

```
angular.module("webclient.constants", [])
.constant("apiServerConstants", {
    "url": "http://localhost:8080"
});

angular.module('webclient', [
  // some stuff
  'webclient.constants'
  ])
  .config(
    // some code
  });

angular.module('webclient')
  .factory('AuthService', ['$http', 'apiServerConstants', 'localStorageService', function($http, localStorageService, apiServerConstants) {

    return {
      authenticate: function(data) {
        // some code
      },
      login: function(data, apiServerConstants) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(apiServerConstants.url);
        // some more code
       }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Probably because you call `login` with only one argument.

Comment: Makes sense. Given I return an object rather than the result of a function, the caller of `login()` should pass it in, or I remove from the params for scope reasons.

Comment: I guess the function signature should be `login: function(data) {` because you already have `apiServerConstants`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted your injections.

`['$http', 'apiServerConstants', 'localStorageService', function($http, localStorageService, apiServerConstants)` should be `['$http', 'localStorageService', 'apiServerConstants', function($http, localStorageService, apiServerConstants)`

**EDIT:**

And why is `apiServerConstants` a parameter of `login`? Try this:

```
login: function(data) {
    console.log(apiServerConstants.url);
}
```

Comment: Goof catch, but after flipping them, I still get `undefined` for `apiServerConstants`.

Comment: Yea, two compounding bugs I just failed to see. Thanks!